# scala assignment of value vs. reference types

Tags: scala

I thought I had a firm grasp of Scala's treatment of reference types (i.e., those derived from AnyRef), but now I am not so sure.

If I create a simple class like this

```
class C(var x: Int = 0) {}
```

and define a few instances

```
var a = new C
var b = new C(1)
var c = new C(2)
```

and then I assign

```
a = b
```

I do not get a (shallow) copy, but rather the original reference to the instance to a is lost forever, and a and b are essentially "aliases" for the same object. (This can be seen by looking at the addresses of these items.) This is fine and sensible. It is also clear that these are references (as opposed to values), since I can do

```
c = null
```

and this does not generate an error.

Now, suppose I do this

```
import scala.math.BigInt
var x = BigInt("12345678987654321")
var y = BigInt("98765432123456789")
var z = x + y
```

This creates three BigInts, with x, y and z, as, I suppose, references to these. In fact, I can do

```
z = null
```

and again get no error. However,

```
y = x
x += 1
```

does **not** cause y to change, i.e., it appears that in this case assignment did not simply create another "name" for the object referred to by x, but made a copy of it.

Why does this happen? I cannot find any mechanism (e.g., akin to the "copy constructor" of C++) that would be silently invoked by (what appears to be) straightforward reference assignment.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated, as two days of web search has proved fruitless.

Answer (score 5):

`x += 1` [will be expanded into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779270/298389) `x = x + 1` so it's not only assignment.

If you will look at the source of bigInt you'll see that + creates new instance:

```
def +  (that: BigInt): BigInt = new BigInt(this.bigInteger.add(that.bigInteger))
```

in fact it uses java's BigInteger underneath whose add operations leaves both arguments untouched.

So what basically happens at the end of the day is *reference reassignment of result of copy constructor of immutable addition*

Comment: `x += 1` will only be expanded to `x = x + 1` if `x` doesn't define a method named `+=`. Otherwise, that method is going to be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = x
x += 1
```

BigInt is immutable so +1 creates new BigInt that's why y does not change. `y` still points to  previous object while `x` points to new BigInt object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose its related to the immutability of BigInt and similar classes, you always get a new immutable object.